# How to arrange list using lambda or linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

**How to arrange list using lambda or linq.**
 Following is the list (Tickets), The list having a field called MessageId", each MessageId        may or may not contains sub messages and so on (ie, ReplyMessageId).

I have the following list

```
   MessageId        ReplyMessageId       Message                    PostedDate

  66                  65             "Hello"                    6/25/2013 10:00:01 AM
  68                  66             "[Reply to Hello]-1"       6/25/2013 10:12:23 AM
  72                  66             "[Reply to Hello]-2"       6/25/2013 11:12:23 AM
  73                  66             "[Reply to Hello]-3"       6/26/2013 9:12:23 AM
  74                  66             "[Reply to Hello]-4"       6/25/2013 11:12:12 PM
  75                  68             "[Reply to Hello-1] -1"    6/25/2013 11:05:12 AM
  76                  73             "[Reply to Hello-3] -1"    6/26/2013 10:10:23 AM
  80                  75             "[Reply to Hello-1-1] -1"  6/25/2013 11:45:22 AM
  81                  68             "[Reply to Hello-1]-1"     6/25/2013 11:45:22 AM
```

For example, MessageId 68 is the reply of MessageId 66 and MessageId 68 having sub messages 75,81.

The output list should be in the following format.

```
  MessageId        ReplyMessageId       Message                    PostedDate

  66                  65             "Hello"                    6/25/2013 10:00:01 AM
  74                  66             "[Reply to Hello]-4"       6/25/2013 11:12:12 PM
  73                  66             "[Reply to Hello]-3"       6/26/2013 9:12:23 AM
  76                  73             "[Reply to Hello-3]-1"     6/26/2013 10:10:23 AM
  72                  66             "[Reply to Hello]-2"       6/25/2013 11:12:23 AM
  68                  66             "[Reply to Hello]-1"       6/25/2013 10:12:23 AM
  81                  68             "[Reply to Hello-1]-1"     6/25/2013 11:45:22 AM
  75                  68             "[Reply to Hello-1]-1"     6/25/2013 11:05:12 AM
  80                  75             "[Reply to Hello-1-1]-1"   6/25/2013 11:45:22 AM
```

Comment: Try something like this `var test = msgs.OrderByDescending(x => x.MessageId).ThenByDescending(x => x.PostedDate);`

Comment: Your second table doesn't match the definition; it is not "ordered by MessageId,Posted date in descending order" - since your first column MessageId is neither strictly ascending nor descending (...72,68,81,75,80,...). Presumably, then, this relates somehow to ReplyMessageId - but: can you define your intent more clearly, please?

Comment: Frankly, personally I'd just construct this as a hierarchical (rather than flat) object model; much easier to work with

Comment: As I understand your `message` is represented by `MessageId`, so what is `sub-message` represented by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just build the tree; much simpler than trying to handle it while flat:

```
class MessageItem
{
    private readonly List<MessageItem> children = new List<MessageItem>();
    public List<MessageItem> Children { get { return children; } }
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public int ReplyMessageId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedDate { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} ({1}): {2}", MessageId, ReplyMessageId, Message);
    }
}
static void Main()
{
    // input data
    var cu = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    var data = new[] {
        new MessageItem{ MessageId = 66, ReplyMessageId = 65, Message = "Hello", PostedDate = DateTime.Parse("6/25/2013 10:00:01 AM", cu)},
        new MessageItem{ MessageId = 68, ReplyMessageId = 66, Message = "[Reply to Hello]-1", PostedDate = DateTime.Parse("6/25/2013 10:12:23 AM",cu)},
        new MessageItem{ MessageId = 72, ReplyMessageId = 66, Message = "[Reply to Hello]-2", PostedDate = DateTime.Parse("6/25/2013 11:12:23 AM",cu)},
        new MessageItem{ MessageId = 73, ReplyMessageId = 66, Message = "[Reply to Hello]-3", PostedDate = DateTime.Parse("6/26/2013 9:12:23 AM",cu)},
        new MessageItem{ MessageId = 74, ReplyMessageId = 66, Message = "[Reply to Hello]-4", PostedDate = DateTime.Parse("6/25/2013 11:12:12 PM",cu)},
        new MessageItem{ MessageId = 75, ReplyMessageId = 68, Message = "[Reply to Hello-1] -1", PostedDate = DateTime.Parse("6/25/2013 11:05:12 AM",cu)},
        new MessageItem{ MessageId = 76, ReplyMessageId = 73, Message = "[Reply to Hello-3] -1", PostedDate = DateTime.Parse("6/26/2013 10:10:23 AM",cu)},
        new MessageItem{ MessageId = 80, ReplyMessageId = 75, Message = "[Reply to Hello-1-1] -1", PostedDate = DateTime.Parse("6/25/2013 11:45:22 AM",cu)},
        new MessageItem{ MessageId = 81, ReplyMessageId = 68, Message = "[Reply to Hello-1]-1", PostedDate = DateTime.Parse("6/25/2013 11:45:22 AM",cu)},
    };

    // build the hierarchy, using a parent lookup
    var ids = data.ToDictionary(x => x.MessageId);
    List<MessageItem> orphans = new List<MessageItem>();
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        MessageItem parent;
        (ids.TryGetValue(item.ReplyMessageId, out parent) ? parent.Children : orphans).Add(item);
    }

    // write the hierarchy using a stack (to avoid recursion)
    Stack<MessageItem> pending = new Stack<MessageItem>();
    // the following looks backwards, but isn't (the stack reverses the order)
    // personally, I would use => x.PostedDate, but that gives a different order
    // (the *correct* order, IMO); this gives the *requested* order; no point
    // ordering *after* MessageId, as presumably that is unique
    foreach (var msg in orphans.OrderBy(x => x.MessageId)) pending.Push(msg); 
    while (pending.Count > 0)
    {
        var next = pending.Pop();
        Console.WriteLine(next);
        foreach (var msg in next.Children.OrderBy(x => x.MessageId)) pending.Push(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great work... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sanooj saying thanks with a +1 up-vote would be better.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, I want to show the list in hierarchical way, So can you add a property(say "MarginLeft") in the resulting list with some values.